# Photo on the lowest side of the header

Tags: graphics, header-footer, wallpaper

I am trying to add a photo on the header. I thought of using [`wallpaper` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper). My simple code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[margin=2.8cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}%\vspace{1cm}
\ULCornerWallPaper{0.2}{headerPhoto}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

and the output is

[image]

As you can see the photo is placed **exactly** at the upper left corner. I believe it would be more fancy to look like that

[image]

righter and lower, that is. I tried to use `hspace{}` and `\vspace{}` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea on that?

Comment: Any reason you can't use `fancyhdr`? It's designed for putting things in the header and footer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command `\ULCornerWallPaper` doesn't accept any offset, but `\CenterWallPaper` does.

You can use the lengths `\wpXoffset` and `\wpYoffset` to adjust the position in the page.

In the example below I've set

```
\addtolength{\wpXoffset}{-5.8cm}
\addtolength{\wpYoffset}{12.5cm}
```

but you will have to change these values to accomplish the positioning of your image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{mwe} % only for the example
\usepackage[margin=2.8cm]{geometry}
\addtolength{\wpXoffset}{-5.8cm}
\addtolength{\wpYoffset}{12.5cm}

\begin{document}
\CenterWallPaper{0.15}{example-image-a} % change back to your image
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It works like a charm!!!

Comment: @Thanos You're welcome. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `tikz` and `background` packages too. Unlike `wallpaper` these two packages allow you to put the picture anywhere in the page. I have given an example with `tikz` below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[margin=2.8cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] 
at ($(current page.north west) + (3.5cm,-.4cm) $) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}; 
% change back to your image. In (3.5cm,-.4cm) => (<xvalue>, <yvalue>) postive xvalue moves the picture 
% to the right and negative yvalue moves it below
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]